# Implement F# List.scan in C?

Tags: c, f#

How would you implement a function with the same behavior as `List.scan` in F#?

Here is the description:

> Applies a function to each element of the collection, threading an
>   accumulator argument through the computation. This function takes the
>   second argument, and applies the function to it and the first element
>   of the list. Then, it passes this result into the function along with
>   the second element, and so on. Finally, it returns the list of
>   intermediate results and the final result. ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.scan%5B%27t%2C%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D))

Of course I have attempted myself and here is my pseudocode (I do not expect you to provide working c-code btw): For the call `scan(myop, ne, x)`, I have the pseudocode

```
int n = length(x);
char *b = (char*)malloc(n); //Allocate n bytes
b[0] = ne;
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    bool tmp = myop(b[i-1], x[i]);
    bool b[i] = tmp;
    i = i+1;
}
bool list y = b;
```

but this fails for `i > 0` since then `b[i]` is not initialized. How would *you* implement this?

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

> but this fails for i > 0 since then b[i] is not initialized

In your pseudo code:

```
bool tmp = myop(b[i-1], x[i]);
```

It will be failed when `i = 0` (it means at the first time you enter the while loop), because you try to access the index `-1` (`i = 0`, so `b[i-1]` becomes `b[-1]`) of `b`, it is undefined behavior.

You have to begin the `while` loop at `i = 1` at least. So, before the loop:

```
b[0] = ne;
int i = 0;
```

Can change to:

```
b[0] = ne;
// do something with b[0] if you want.
int i = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you refer to the previous element even for `i == 0`, which is incorrect. You could special case the first element by storing `b[0] = myop(ne, x[0])` and start the loop at `i = 1`, but this solution would not work for an empty source list (`n == 0`). Furthermore, `length(x)` cannot be computed from a pointer, only from an actual array as `sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x)`. It is best to pass the size as a separate argument.

Here is a C function that performs the semantics of `List.scan` for `int` arguments, taking a pointer to the function, an initial value, an array of `int` values, the length of this array and a pointer to the destination array, which can be the same as the source array:

```c
int array_scan(int (*func)(int, int), int v1, const int *src, size_t count, int *dest) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int v2 = src[i];
        dest[i] = v1;
        v1 = func(v1, v2);
    }
    return v0;
}
```

In C there is no way to define lambda expressions inline, so you must define the function separately with a name and pass it explicitly to `array_scan`.